# PHP MySQL error on INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am really pulling my hair out on this one. I got a simple comment section on my self-built php app and I simply want to add a new row if I catch a $_GET parameter. But no matter how I build the MySQL insert request, I get an error.

This is what I have so far:

```
if(isset($_GET['r'])){
    $replyid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['r']);
    $sentnow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO eis_inbox (messageid, toid, from, contact, seen, message, date) VALUES (NULL, '".$replyid."', 'TESTUSER', 'CONTACTINFO', '0', 'MESSAGE', '".$sentnow."'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;/messages">';
}
```

My MySQL DB fields are called exactly the same: messageid (auto_increment), toid(int11), from(varchar255), contact(varchar255), seen(int3), message(text) and date(timestamp/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Executing the above page with let's say "index.php?r=777" should, as I see it, populate my MySQL with a new row as such:

```
messageid = (AUTO_INCREMENT)
toid = 777
from = TESTUSER
contact = CONTACTINFO
seen = 0
message = MESSAGE
date = 2013-01-17 11:50:01
```

Instead, I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, contact, seen, message, date) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'TESTUSER', 'CONTACTINFO'' at line 1
```

Same error shown with "error_reporting(E_ALL)".

I have looked into this for several days now, and I just can't find the error... Perhaps I am blind and miss a comma or closing tag or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Learn about prepared statements instead, use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: I am not sure whether $replyid is an int in your database, but if it is you shouldn't use the symbols '' around it. (only for strings)

Comment: Make sure the datatype for the seen field, is either varchar, or remove the '' around the value for it.

Comment: when inserting an integer, do not encapsulate it with single quotes. try that

Comment: thank you. i know. this is an old perfectly working app which needs a little maintenance. so i don't want to change everything just to be up-to-date with latest developments. which is why i probably have trouble updating this old code.

Comment: $replyid is a varchar11 in my db. datatype for 'seen' changed to varchar3 with same results. same applies to changing the INSERT statement without quotes.

Comment: pls tell me why this got downvoted? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in here :

- There is a missing parenthesis at the end of your generated query.
- `from` and `date` are reserved keywords, enclose them in `.
- `seen` and `toid` are not `varchar` fields, and therefore their values shouldn't be enclosed in `'`.

Try :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO eis_inbox (messageid, toid, `from`, contact, seen, message, `date`)
VALUES (NULL, ".$replyid.", 'TESTUSER', 'CONTACTINFO', 0, 'MESSAGE', '".$sentnow."')");
```

Warning : this is vulnerable to SQL injections. Don't use `mysql_*` commands, try [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) ou [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php) instead. Prepared statements will help avoiding them.

Comment: This did the trick totally! THANKS A BUNCH! Going to accept this as an answer!

Comment: Last one is awful. While their current code actually invulnerable to injection, your version made it vulnerable. -1

Comment: How so? Isn't $_GET properly escaped?

Comment: that's just an example folks. the values for the rows are coming from all over the place. Just made this example up for easier q&a.

Answer (score 5):

Its bcause you're using reserved words (from and date) as column names.

Wrap them around with ``

ie:

```
INSERT INTO eis_inbox (`messageid`, `toid`, `from`, `contact`, `seen`, `message`, `date`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Date is keyword of mysql you have to enclose it within ` sign. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) is the complete list of reserved words in MySQL from official documentation for future use.

Apart from this the parenthesis for values is not closed.

Use this. I hope this will work fine.

```
INSERT INTO eis_inbox (`messageid`, `toid`, `from`, `contact`, `seen`, `message`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '".$replyid."', 'TESTUSER', 'CONTACTINFO', '0', 'MESSAGE', '".$sentnow."')"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use reserved word in mysql direct

from  is reserved word

short example

```
INSERT INTO eis_inbox (messageid, from) VALUES (1,2);
```

-- is bad query

```
INSERT INTO eis_inbox (messageid, `from`) VALUES (1,2);
```

-- is correct query

but better is avoid such situation. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) is the complete list of reserved words in MySQL from official documentation for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing an closing tag for the values, and from is preserved, so you should escape it... (use quotes around it should do the trick,...:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO eis_inbox (messageid, toid, from, contact, seen, message, date) VALUES (NULL, '".$replyid."', 'TESTUSER', 'CONTACTINFO', '0', 'MESSAGE', '".$sentnow."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO eis_inbox (messageid, toid, 'from', contact, seen, message, date) VALUES (NULL, '".$replyid."', 'TESTUSER', 'CONTACTINFO', '0', 'MESSAGE', '".$sentnow."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also as zan mentioned, don use mysql_* functions, but mysqli_* or PDO...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO eis_inbox (messageid, toid, from, contact, seen, message, date) VALUES (NULL, '".$replyid."', 'TESTUSER', 'CONTACTINFO', '0', 'MESSAGE', '".$sentnow."')") or die(mysql_error());
```